# Unable to edit user address in contact card

Tags: google-api, location, google-contacts-api

I have been working with Google Workspace Support for over 2 months and they were unable to help me figure out how to edit an address in a contact card and recommended I reach out here. We were able to see where the address is(image included) but are not able to edit it. [Address API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcP2w.png)
The address is labeled "Office location". We tried to add "Work location" but the old address still shows up underneath (image included). [Work location Office location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOcu0.png) The old address shows up on about 16 users. The rest of our users have correct "Office location" addresses.

Comment: Former Googler here. It's disappointing to hear that Google Support was unable to help. They should be able to liaise with Engineering if they don't understand the problem. Your question is unclear. Do I understand correctly that the `location` tagged `Office location` should be deleted and the Boston MA address (`Work`) is its intended replacement? How are you attempting to make these changes? Are you using `Try this method` on the [`update`](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/update) method page? Or are you using code?

Comment: The [`update`](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/update) methiod patches the `User` and [`locations`](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users#User.FIELDS.locations) is an array. So, in theory (!) replacing the entire `locations` array with a single entry of your new work location, should (!?) effect the change you're seeking.